# How to manage a redirect request after a fetch post call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I am using fetch to communicate with the node server(Express). I am building a SPA. On each request to the server I am checking if the session is valid or not. If the session is not valid I am redirecting from node to a login page. The problem is that. If the session is getting invalidated(for eg: get/post request running in the background without a page refresh) the request is failing silently. It is not getting redirected.

I had the same issue for the ajax request also. What I had done is by checking the request is xhr and accept json. Then send a json response and handle the redirect in the frond end.

```
if (req.xhr && req.accepts('json')) {
  res.json({status:'session_timeout'});
}else{
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

How can I do the same by using fetch. How do I handle redirect using fetch and node.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from you're code how you are determining if a session is valid. It looks like you are testing to see if the request is the one you are sending from the browser, and if it is, then to respond with the json.

In this case when would the redirect ever be triggered? If you are always sending the request from the browser, it will never make it to the redirect statement.

Have you tried using passport for user authentication? It is easy to set up middleware that you can include in all your endpoints, so that each request would be redirected if the user was not still logged in.

for example:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Then in your api:

```
app.get('/yourendpoint', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    /*response here*/
    });
});
```